# Elmah on Azure the XML log files

Tags: xml, azure, web-config, elmah

I want to move my MVC 4 app to Azure and incure no other data storage costs outside of the basic Azure web role. Currently, I store the Elmah logs in the app_data directory as xml files. I also keep other serialized data files there.

In Azure I have to use LocalStorage, which is fine for everything except Elmah. Elmah determines where to store the xml files based on UNC path in the web.config, not file path.

Is there anyway to change elmah to participate in the localstorage model of Azure? If it doesn't, my only choice is in-memory which is lost when the app goes down or the deployment is cycled.

Comment: I should say I'm using Azure sdk 1.8. On a related note, why does the azure cloud project's mvc project has the app_data folder if I can't use it on Azure?

Comment: I'm able to use App_Data in my Asp.net mvc4 Azure web role, and I don't see a reason for not being able to use it. Could you share what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Two responses:
1) To DFBerry - see [This write up (including NuGet package) on using ELMAH with Azure Table storage.](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/using-elmah-in-windows-azure-with-table-storage/)

2) To Guy - I'm trying to to do that now, and what I'm getting is nothing - ELMAH doesn't log anything, even though I know I'm throwing exceptions.  I have it configured with XmlFileErrorLog, and the path pointed to ~/App_Data.  I did get something there one time, but it was when there was a Web.config error relating to Elmah itself. Go figure.  But I do believe you're right - that you can, in fact, write to App_Data, though you will have problems if you scale your site to multiple instances. So I don't understand why I'm having such difficulty.